# Mixed Fractional Equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

$$3 \frac{3}{5}  +  \frac{2}{x} = 4\frac{4}{15}$$

I tried subtracting by both sides, etc,
but it didn't come out right.
I also tried multiplying by both sides, but, it didn't seem to work.
what would be the proper way to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Clear the denominators by multiplying by the LCM.  You want the LCM of $\{5,x,15\}$  What do you think that is?  Please show your work, don't just say your work fails.  If we see it, we can help find the problem.

Comment: 18/5 + 2/x =4 4/15.. multiply both sides by 5, 18 +2/x =21 1/3, subtract both sides by 18, 2=2x x=1?

Comment: I think I'm wrong :/

Comment: If you multiply by $15x$ you clear all the denominators, getting $54x+30=64x$.  In your approach, you failed to multiply the $2/x$ by $5$, so you should have gotten $18+10/x=21\ 1/3$, then subtracting $18$ would leave $10/x=3\ 1/3$

Comment: oops :) I failed xD

Answer (score 2):

Lets convert the mixed fractions into improper fractions to get the equivalent equation:

$\frac{18}{5}+\frac{2}{x}=\frac{64}{15}$

We now multiply nominator and denominator of the first fraction by three so that both fractions have the same denominator:

$\frac{54}{15}+\frac{2}{x}=\frac{64}{15}$

We now isolate the term $\frac{2}{x}$:

$\frac{2}{x}=\frac{64}{15}-\frac{54}{15}$

We do the fraction substraction:

$\frac{2}{x}=\frac{64-54}{15}=\frac{10}{15}$

We then mutiply by $15$ to get:

$\frac{30}{x}=10$

We multiply by $x$ to get:

$30=10x$

Finally we divide by $10$ to get:
$x=\frac{30}{10}$ which is $3$.

Answer (score 1):

$3\frac{3}{5}=\frac{18}{5}=\frac{54}{15}$

$4\frac{4}{15}=\frac{64}{15}$

Now,

$\frac{2}{x}=\frac{64}{15}-\frac{54}{15}=\frac{10}{15}$

Taking reciprocals,

$\frac{x}{2}=\frac{15}{10}$

$x=\frac{15}{5}=3$

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So I assume you are trying to solve for $x$. So first we do this:

$$\frac{2}{x} = 4\frac{4}{15}-\frac{18}{5} = \frac{64}{15}-\frac{54}{15} = \frac{2}{3}$$
Then $$2 = x\frac{2}{3} \implies x = \frac{2}{\frac{2}{3}} = 3$$

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$ \pm k\frac{a}{b}=\pm k\pm \frac{a}{b} $$
So now we have
$$3 \frac{3}{5}  +  \frac{2}{x} = 4\frac{4}{15}$$
$$  \frac{2}{x} = 4\frac{4}{15}- 3 \frac{3}{5} = 4\frac{4}{15}- 3 \frac{9}{15} $$
$$  \frac{2}{x} = 1-\frac{5}{15} = \frac33-\frac{1}{3}=\frac23 $$
Therefore 
$$ x=3 $$